# Need to find the count difference by category wise

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, sum

[image: Attached the image]

Description:

Need to find the sum of premium mismatch between two tables - if the sum of premium for particular category is not matched with Agent table then i want that to be capture

Desired result set

Sum of premium should be grouped by Category in this case sum of MTT is 219 in Demo but in Agent table sum of MTT is 221

So in this case my query should capture the mismatch and put the result as below (only for mismatch and if we do not have any mismatch then display 0)

Sum(premium) from Demo  Minus Sum(premium) from Agent

Answer (score 1):

consider below approach

```
select category, sum(premium) as diff
from (
  select premium, category from Demo 
  union all
  select -premium, category from Agent 
)
group by category
```

Comment: this query will give us the sum of premium  (group by category) but my question is different

Comment: premium should be grouped by Category column in tablea and tableb and if we do see any mismatch for ex: sum of premium is 450 for the Category "MTT" in TAble1 and sum of premium is 400 for category "MTT" in table2 then i need to fetch only these records and do the  mean calc

Comment: @Ram . . . This pretty much answers the questions that you asked here.  Nothing in your question talks about taking averages.  You might want a `having` clause, but that seems like a minor adjustment to the query.